# Extra padding only in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I get a strange padding in an `h3` tag only in Chrome. The strangest thing is that I can't prevent it or control it through CSS and when I select the text of `h3` it seems that the selection expands to the right and bottom of the text.

Preview in Chrome:

[image]

Preview in other browsers:

[image]

This extra padding in Chrome causes misalignments and it expands the height of the container, which is undesired.

**[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BbJhE/)**.

Can you please help me locate the problem?

Note: I use CSS reset, I tried `line-height`, `margin` instead of `padding` but no luck.

Comment: Did you use a CSS reset?

Comment: @Diodeus Yes! I load CSS reset before the actual styling css

Comment: Technically Chrome no longer uses Webkit (it's got it's own version called Blink).

Comment: @j08691 OK... webkit tag removed

Comment: which reset are you using?
in my test-example on a localhost with my reset.css, i dont get the space. try my [reset.css](http://www.walter-it.de/reset.css) or check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BbJhE/2/)

Comment: Are you setting a hard line-height for the H3?

Comment: @MichaelWalter I'm using almost the same reset.css. Try selecting the `h3` text in your fiddle and you'll still see the bottom padding there like the 1st image I posted.

Comment: @Lowkase `line-height` is not making any difference. I tried everything.

Comment: @otinanai i don't see the padding/margin. chrome: Version 28.0.1500.72 m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `line-height: 0;` to the div:

```
#mailing div {
    line-height: 0;
}
```

Try also adding:

```
#mailing .moduletable {
    display: table;
}
```

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BbJhE/12/

Comment: Not really. I still get the same issue in Chrome. You can compare your fiddle in FF and see the difference.

Comment: very promising. need to run some tests and coming back to accept or not.

Answer (score 1):

Although this may not be the best solution (because I had to hard code the height of the `<div id="mailing">`)  it does work and remains consistent with both Chrome and FF

I added `height: 2.4em;` to `#mailing`
and `margin:0;` to `#user_email_formAcymailing1.inputbox`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BbJhE/11/

Comment: The form disappeared in FF. I don't see the input or the button.

Comment: Ohh yeah.. that won't work because if you re-size the panel the input and button will move down to the next line. Hard coding the height will hide the input, sorry I'll try to think of something else.

Comment: I thought so... Thanks for trying though

Answer (score 1):

Try removing:

```
table.acymailing_form {
    margin-top: 2%;
}
```

Comment: Yes. This was affecting too. I tried it before accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a hard line-height for the h3:

```
#mailing h3 {
    font:small-caps .95em"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff;
    color:#6b6b6b;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0;
    float:left;
    line-height:20px;
}
```

Comment: Still I get the same behavior as image 1 of my OP. Try selecting the text and you'll see the extra padding. This doesn't happen in any other browser.